# NFS server is exporting the wrong directories

Tags: linux, centos, nfs

It is a bit embarrassing to admit, but I have problems getting my NFS server exporting the right directories. I am using an up-to-date CentOS 6.2 on both the client and the server.

The server is up and running, the firewall was disabled during the tests.

On the server side I have created this `/etc/exports`:

```
/home/user1/documents/   *(ro,sync)
```

this directory is the root of a volume of a software raid. `mount` output as follows:

```
/dev/mapper/lvm--raid-lvol0 on /home/user1/documents type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

the command `showmount -e` on the server shows the correct output:

```
Export list for servername:
/home/user1/documents (everyone)
```

I try to mount that share from the client and get the following output:

```
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting servername:/home/user1/documents
```

However when I look afterwards on the server at the file `/proc/fs/nfsd/exports` I see more than one mountpoint, but not the right one

```
# Version 1.2
# Path Client(Flags) # IPs
/       *(ro,root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,fsid=0,uuid=696f3ea6:3d7641f3:b6315631:bd63c833)
/home   *(ro,root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,uuid=696f3ea6:3d7641f3:b6315631:bd63c833)
/home/user1     *(ro,root_squash,sync,no_wdelay,no_subtree_check,v4root,uuid=696f3ea6:3d7641f3:b6315631:bd63c833)
```

Where do these entries come from and why is there no line starting with `/home/user1/documents` ? I tried mounting `/home/user1` instead of `/home/user1/documents` from the client and this strangely works.

The UIDs of the user are the same on the server and the client. Could it be a problem that the directory to be exported is mounted itself?

**Edit**

The file `/var/lib/nfs/xtab` is empty.

Comment: For completeness (if the problem still exists) what does /var/lib/nfs/[ex]tab contain?

Comment: This file is empty (I updated my question). The problem still exists.

Comment: Have you tried mounting without the trailing slash? "/home/user1/documents" instead of "/home/user1/documents/". Also I have never used "*" before, so can't validate that; try using the ip address also. Also, try -v when mounting on the client side. And are there any more routers/firewalls involved between the 2 systmes? Is there a NAT in use (a NAT would cause this due to using an unprivileged port, which should show up if you use -v)?

Comment: @GorillaPatch is /var/lib/nfs/etab also empty ?

Comment: @GorillaPatch: Is this `/home/user1/documents/   *(ro,sync)` the only content at your `/etc/exports`?

Comment: yes it is. I am at the moment exporting this directory only.

Comment: @peter no there is no NAT they a attached to the very same switch without any routers on the same subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are using NFSv4 (the fsid=0 in the /proc/fs/nfsd/exports output gives it away). NFS roots are rquired for NFSv4. You may have better luck with this /etc/exports.

```
/home                    *(ro,fsid=0)
/home/user1/documents/   *(ro,sync)
```

You might also need to edit the domain in /etc/idmapd.conf for the server and clients.

On a side note, I highly recommend replacing that asterisk with a subnet if you don't want your data accessable to untrusted systems.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The asterisk is there for debugging purposes only. Where can I find documentation about NFS roots? This is kind of new to me. I have not seen it in NFSv3.

Comment: The arch wiki has a good guide for NFSv4. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFSv4

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem with:

```
/my/dir1 *(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
/my/dir2 *(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
```

and both mount appeared for `/my/dir1`.

I was trying to use the same default options as given in the Ubuntu 16.04 `nfs-kernel-server` package `/etc/exports` example file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198009/what-provides-etc-exports-and-how-do-i-find-that-out

The solution was to remove `fsid=0,crossmnt` and use just:

```
/my/dir1 *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/my/dir2 *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

This is also mentioned at: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/481263-NFS-directs-to-the-wrong-shared-folder/page2?s=ae345ec054b854b5cf036cd1816626f4

I don't really know what all of those do, one day I'll learn NFS. Maybe.